# 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppDelegateSwizzler.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Swift 5.
My pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SocialBoards' do
  platform :ios, '10.0'
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.2'
  pod 'Arrow', '~> 5.1.0'
  pod 'HandyJSON', '~> 5.0.0-beta.1'
  pod 'AttributedTextView', '~> 1.4.1'
  pod 'SwiftOverlays', '~> 5.0.1'
  pod 'Toaster', '2.2.0'
  pod 'SmileLock', '~> 3.0.7'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '3.14.0'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.15.0'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.8.0' # usage: \https://cocoapods.org/pods/NVActivityIndicatorView
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.0' # usage: \https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift
  pod 'SwiftEventBus', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'RTIconButton','~> 1.1.7' # usage: \https://github.com/rickytan/RTIconButton
  pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
  pod 'WELCustomStatusbarColor','~>1.0.5'
  pod 'TableFlip' #TableView animations \https://github.com/mergesort/TableFlip
  pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift5'
  pod "KeyboardAdjuster", "~> 4.0.0"
  pod "MIBadgeButton-Swift", :git => 'https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift.git', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'JSQMessagesViewController' #usage: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController , https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2 - tutorial
  pod 'Auk', '~> 11.0.0' #https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 3.0' #https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField
  pod 'SwiftSoup', '~> 2.3.0' #https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup
  pod "PromiseKit", "~> 6.12.0" #https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit
  pod 'PromiseKit/Alamofire', '~> 6.12.0' #https://github.com/PromiseKit/Alamofire-
  pod "FlagPhoneNumber", :git => 'https://github.com/chronotruck/FlagPhoneNumber.git', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'PinLayout', '~> 1.8.7'
  pod 'LNZTreeView', '~> 1.1.2'
  pod 'MarqueeLabel', '~> 4.0.2' #https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel
  pod 'DropDown', '2.3.13' #Dropdown menu. Usage: https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown
  pod 'DeviceKit', '~> 2.0' #https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit
  pod 'WSTagsField', '5.2.0' #https://github.com/whitesmith/WSTagsField
  pod 'InitialsImageView', '0.7.0' #https://github.com/bachonk/InitialsImageView
  pod 'SimpleCheckbox', '2.1.0' #https://github.com/BeauNouvelle/SimpleCheckbox
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Cosmos', '~> 20.0' #https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos - star rating
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    next unless target.name == 'SwiftSoup'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      next unless config.name.start_with?('Release')
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
    end
  end
end
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
pod update 'GoogleUtilities'
```

update the above pod or install the above pod.